# Suitable object type for a 2D look-up table of unknown size created at runtime

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, lookup, memory-efficient

I'm writing a Python 3.4 script that does a large calculation for me. This calculation involves calculating *many many* [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), and using each of them many times in sums and multiplications with other numbers. Each time a bc (binomial coefficient) is needed in the calculation, it checks whether the bc has already been calculated. If so, it returns this already calculated value. Otherwise, it calculates it and stores it for later look-up. Currently, my function bc(n,k), which calculates the bc "n choose k", looks as follows:

```
bcvalues = {}

def bc(n,k):
    k = min(k,n-k) # take advantage of symmetry
    if (n,k) in bcvalues: # check whether value has already been calculated
        return bcvalues[(n,k)] # if so, return that already calculated value
    if k == 0 or n <= 1: # base case
        return 1
    result = bc(n-1,k) + bc(n-1,k-1) # Use formula for Pascal's triangle
    bcvalues[(n,k)] = result # store the value for later look-up
    return result
```

My look-up table is a dictionary with the (n,k) tuple as the key and bc(n,k) as the value. It satisfies all the

**Strict requirements**

1. Can be filled / extended to an arbitrary size at runtime (before the calculation runs, I have *no idea* how many bc's it needs to calculate, but it's a *lot* of bc's)
2. The values can be arbitrarily large (either `int` (the Python 3 one) or the [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) type `mpz`, I'm not sure yet). This is important as the values can become very very large
3. It can be indexed by two natural numbers n and k
4. The bc's for some tuples (n,k) can be skipped (e.g. there may be an entry for (100,50) but no entry for (100,49))

However, I'm not sure whether it is "the" optimal solution (if there is one) in terms of the

**Performance requirements** (in the order of importance)

5. Fast look-up / read-out
6. Low memory-usage (in tests, my dictionary already occupied several GBs; I may eventually rent computing power on large-memory machines)
7. Fast writing into the look-up table

In very small input size tests that I've just run, the function bc was called 16 million times, and this number is likely to grow a lot for input sizes that I'm actually interested in. Therefore, performance matters.

My current solution (dictionary) has the advantage that at the end of a computation run, I can serialize the look-up table (using pickle), so that when I perform a new run with higher input values, I can unpickle it and have all the bc's at hand that have been calculated in previous runs. This is a *strong* bonus point:

**Bonus point**

8. The look-up table can easily be serialized

**My question**

What, besides dictionary, could be a candidate for matching these criteria?

I thought of writing a function that maps tuples (n,k) of the triangle bijectively to natural numbers and then use a list for the look-up table. How promising is this? Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I maintain `gmpy2`.

Once you start working with integers longer than 50 to 100 decimal digits, you should be using `gmpy2.mpz`.

A dictionary seems like the best choice. Indexing a list is slightly faster than a dictionary lookup but the overhead of mapping (n,k) to an index value makes it slower on my system.

There may be a way to decrease the memory usage. You calculate binomial coefficient recursively and save all the intermediate values. `bcvalues` will get very large. If you don't need all the binomial coefficients for smaller values of `n` and `k` then you might try using `gmpy2.comb` to calculate the binomial coefficient and not saving all the intermediate values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would like to know what gmpy2.comb does. Where can I find its source code?

Comment: @CorsinPfister The code is part of the GMP library (www.gmplib.org). `gmpy2.comb` calls `mpz_bin_ui`. A faster version called `mpz_bin_uiui` can be used if both arguments are small enough. I've done some quick tests and it does appear to be faster. I'll update my answer when I'm done testing. BTW, what are the range of values for n and k? Do you frequently reuse the same values?